# How do I create a CMVideoFormatDescription object

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-video

I get a CVPixelBuffer from ARSessionDelegate.

There is another unchangeable part of my app where I need a CMSampleBuffer object. So I am trying to create a CMSampleBuffer out of CVPixelBuffer.

I am using this method to create CMSampleBuffer:

```
func CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer(_ allocator: CFAllocator?, 
                                        _ imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer, 
                                        _ formatDescription: CMVideoFormatDescription, 
                                        _ sampleTiming: UnsafePointer<CMSampleTimingInfo>, 
                                        _ sBufOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CMSampleBuffer?>) -> OSStatus
```

This function takes 5 parameters:

1. CFAllocator - I believe this is not required.
2. imageBuffer - This is the CVPixelBuffer.
3. CMVideoFormatDescription - **How do I correctly create this?**
4. sampleTiming: I could figure out how to create this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48107718/2891327).
5. sBufOut - Just a pointer to the CMSampleBuffer object I want to create.

Here is my attempt at create a CMVideoFormatDescription:

```
    let w = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let h = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
    var format: CMVideoFormatDescription?
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreate(nil, kCMVideoCodecType_HEVC, Int32(w), Int32(h), nil, &format)
```

I am pretty sure I should not be hardcoding to `kCMVideoCodecType_HEVC`but I am not sure how to figure out the codec type.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer` to create the format description directly from the CVPixelBuffer (which is a CVImageBuffer).

Comment: can you give any sample example that can help to create format description directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatDescription: CMVideoFormatDescription?
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(allocator: nil,
                                             imageBuffer: yourCVPixelBuffer,
                                             formatDescriptionOut: &formatDescription)
```